# When is 凝る pronounced こる vs こごる?

Tags: readings

I encountered the following sentence

> ……ものすごく、凝っている！

in the context of a guy giving a boy a doll that the guy himself made (outdoors in the winter, but that is probably not relevant).

I suspect that it is pronounced こる because こごる seems to be closely associated with coldness and freezing, but how could I tell he wasn't for example frozen stiff by holding out his hand out in the cold weather?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no furigana attached to this, you can assume it is read as こる. I didn't know this kanji can be read also as こごる and しこる. The verb こごる itself is rare, and 凍【こお】る and [凍【こご】える](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/77872/meaning/m0u/) are far more common.

Among the 59 results for 凝る in BCCWJ corpus, 58 were clearly こる. There was one example about which I was initially unsure （「凝る雲の底を抜いて、小一日空を傾けた雨は…」）, but this is an excerpt from an old novel, and it seems to be read as こる, too, according to [this](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=FBngWnU3-xEC&lpg=PT272&ots=oudh9saVvH&dq=%E5%87%9D%E3%82%8B%E9%9B%B2%E3%81%AE%E5%BA%95%E3%82%92%E6%8A%9C%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6&hl=ja&pg=PT272#v=onepage&q=%E5%87%9D%E3%82%8B%E9%9B%B2%E3%81%AE%E5%BA%95%E3%82%92%E6%8A%9C%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6&f=false).